# using xcart is it possible to track a successful purchase with google analytics?

Tags: x-cart

With x-cart, is it possible to track successful purchases with Google analytics? If so is this done through the administrative panel or through a php template file?

I need to insert the google analytics goal code into a success page that is unique from others.

Answer (score -1):

That's very easy with X-Cart. See 
http://help.x-cart.com/index.php?title=X-Cart:Google_Analytics

Comment: Yeah but i need to track when you checkout. Not to add google analytics. Google analytics has already been added. Btw your cart software is really hard to use.